# Хочу сделать форму запросов пользователей. Посоветуйте пжлста литературу, инфу, что почитать, поизучать, может библиотеки есть какие-то

Tags: запрос

Всем привет.

Хочу сделать простую форму для отправки фотографий на сервер пользователями с возможностью изменения, корректировок таких фото.

Т.е. сама форма будет в формате 15х10 или 10х15 и клиент будет размещать свои изображения путем кадрирования или по формату целиком и итоговый вариант будет отправляться на печать либо на мою почту, либо на сервер.
Без дизайна, без лишних установок, просто форму.

Может знаете что можно почитать, изучать?
Сам в программировании не особо силен.

Если кто сможет недорого накидать, буду благодарен, сам помогу чем смогу.
Подробнее смогу рассказать в личку.

Хочу сделать что-то типа этого:

1. https://giraffoto.ru/photoprint/#172720_FufM9KNd
2. https://sochi.netprint.ru/sochi/photo/photo-standart#blank_id=24618&paper_type=2&crop_type=fill&improvment=improve
3. https://www.netprint.ru/order/easy-photo?blank_id=24618&paper=2&crop=fill&enh=1#/pick

> [image: Вариант №1]

> [image: Вариант №2]

Comment: Начните с выбора языка на котором будете писать серверную часть. После этого определитесь какой web-сервер будет использоваться. Например nginx умеет сам получать файлы от пользователей и отдавать скрипту ссылки на уже лежащий на диске файл. И наконец выбрав все это вводим в гугле "загрузка файлов на сервер ЯЗЫК" где ЯЗЫК - это то что вы для сервера выбрали. А со стороны клиента, т.е. браузера можно начать хоть со статической формы а можно на JS написать, в том числе могут быть готовые плагины для библиотеки которую вы для отрисовки интерфейса (если) используете

Comment: Спасибо за хорошо раскрытый комментарий. Вы немного просветили меня, в этом вопросе. Мне  также предлагаю двигаться в сторону https://ru.vuejs.org/, поизучать его. 

Вы случайно не знаете он может помочь с интерфейсом для пользователя?

Comment: Да, он предназначен для создания интерфейсов. Но ничего конкретного сказать не могу, никогда не имел дела с полноценными фреймверками.

Comment: А по поводу языка для серверной части, как думаете, для таких целей как у меня, больше подходит PHP или Python ?

Comment: Тот который больше знаете или который по синтаксису больше нравится. Так то оба подходят. Кстати вы там пишите "_Без дизайна, без лишних установок, просто форму_", думаю vue это все таки будет из пушек по воробьям. начните с html формы http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml5/formy/zagruzka-failov А когда задача посложнее станет, красоты захочется, тогда уже vue можно изучать. Фреймверки позволяют сделать что то красивое быстрее чем на голом html, но тогда, когда вы их хорошо знаете, а на изучение может уходить много времени

Comment: Просто я не совсем понимаю как на html можно настроить момент, чтобы пользователь именно изменял фото, т.е. подстраивал свою фотографию под размер 10х15 (обрезал, кардрировал, двигал, поправлял и т.д.). Это оочень важный момент, из-за которого я и собственно хочу такую форму. 

Думаете на голом Html это возможно сделать?

Comment: А, я не внимательно прочитал. Получается вам нужен фактически графический редактор в браузере на стороне клиента. Тут надо какую то библиотеку искать. тот же vue он просто фрайверк, встроенных средств редактирования изображения там не будет. Хотя плагины конечно могут существовать. вот например https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2018/05/8-free-javascript-image-cropping-scripts-and-plugins/ (запрос в гугл был "visual crop image in js" и там еще много интересного

Comment: Да, по сути нужен миниграфический редактор с минимальными возможностями.
В идеале я хочу вот так: https://photo-printing.ru/partner/demo
Случайно нашел этот сайт. Нужно еще добавить возможность редактирования и будет вообще шик.
Я даже готов заплатить и лично помочь в разработке. Если у вас есть время и желание можем списаться в ватсап.